# Online youtube streaming

Tags: apps

The other day, I wanted to watch online stream on YouTube. But was unable to do so, because YouTube in web browser told me online streams are not supported.

Is there any YouTube app which would allow to watch online streams?

Comment: YouTube works for me. Which version of the OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

First of all the error you got is pretty strange. That doesn't happen, you can stream any YouTube video on the browser. If you need further diagnostics you better include all details in the question including OS version and if possible a screenshot of the problem.

And to answer your question you can try out MetroTube, it has a sleek UI and works pretty good.

Comment: I think that in the question context "stream" means "live stream" (online stream are the words that he use).